# cx_freeze and google drive

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I've just read one question about problems when "cx_freezing" a script to upload files to a drive account, so maybe you can help me with something about the same topic.

I'm having problems when executing cx_freeze.exe because it can't find the "google api" modules

how can I specify those modules in order to get the exe correctly done?

Thanks in advance. Kind regards,

Juan-Manuel

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  The correct procedure when asking a question about debugging errors is to share the errors you see...stack traces, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can do `pip install gdata` if you have pip to install automatically.

If you don't have pip, you will have to download it from source and build it yourself from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gdata.

To build cd to the place you downloaded it, extract it and cd into the folder. Then do `python setup.py build`, then to install make sure you are superuser or an Administrator and do `python setup.py install`.